# Using local compute with an Estimator in Azure ML

Tags: azure, tensorflow, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to use local compute for the TensorFlow estimator? Provisioning a virtual machine for a training run takes an enormous amount of time, and I would like to be able to try a few runs locally until my configuration is stable.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/service/how-to-train-tensorflow.md

It is possible to do this with ScriptRunConfig by creating an empty RunConfiguration. The documentation claims that it is possible to create a local ComputeTarget, but the documentation on how to do this is missing:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/service/how-to-set-up-training-targets.md#local

> Local computer
>
> Create and attach: There's no need to create or attach a compute target to use your local computer as the training environment.
>
> Configure: When you use your local computer as a compute target, the training code is run in your development environment. If that environment already has the Python packages you need, use the user-managed environment.
>
> [!code-python]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/) directly, instead of the GitHub raw pages - I've noticed that the latter are sometimes incomplete and/or outdated.

As you suspect, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-set-up-training-targets#local) confirm that you should create an empty RunConfiguration, something like the following code (taken from the aforementioned link):

```python
from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration

# Edit a run configuration property on the fly.
run_local = RunConfiguration()

run_local.environment.python.user_managed_dependencies = True
```

Comment: For me (Mac OS 10.15.5) this didn't work out ... the logs were mentioning something about Docker missing ("Docker was not found on the target, check that it is installed and on the path."), so I installed (and started) Docker Desktop and it worked. Then I stopped Docker and the experiment failed again - so I am pretty sure that at least in my case I had to have a Docker process running locally in order to run Estimator experiments locally.

Answer (score 0):

Use compute_target="local". Adapted [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-train-pytorch)

```py
script_params = {
    '--num_epochs': 30,
    '--output_dir': './outputs'
}

estimator = PyTorch(source_directory=project_folder, 
                    script_params=script_params,
                    # compute_target=compute_target,
                    compute_target='local',
                    entry_script='pytorch_train.py',
                    use_gpu=True,
                    pip_packages=['pillow==5.4.1'])
```